# How to find the value closest to zero using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, zero

Let's say I have a table that could have various numbers in it, for example it could look like the following:

ExampleA:
MyTable
-10,
-3,
5,
10,

ExampleB:
MyTable
-10,
-5,
3,
10,

So if I queried the table in ExampleA I'd want it to return "-3"  (The value closet to 0)

Likewise if I queried the table in ExampleB I'd want it to return "3"  (The value closest to 0)

I always want to find the value that is closest to zero regardless of the numbers in the table, how can I do this?

Also, how could I choose which value for ties (like in the case where the closest value may be -3 and 3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `min()` and `abs()`:

```
select num
from mytable
where abs(num) = (select min(abs(num)) from mytable)
```

To break ties, apply min() or max() to num to get the negative or positive side, eg

To get the negative of a tie:

```
select min(num) num 
from mytable
where abs(num) = (select min(abs(num)) from mytable)
```

To get the positive of a tie:

```
select max(num) num
from mytable
where abs(num) = (select min(abs(num)) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Select top 1 with ties num
From tbl
Group by num
Order by abs(num) asc
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1833/1)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This solution worked but cannot easily be used as a sub query.