# Value Closest to Zero Grouped by Other Fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, closest

I need to write a query that will give me the field value closest to zero. Other submissions on this forum I have found do not take into account other fields in the table. What I need is the value closest to zero grouped on other fields so that each grouping of data has a value closest to zero. This means I could I have 20 rows of data but the values closest to zero are based on additional fields. The query example I have shown is based on what I found in the forum here: [How to find the value closest to zero using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967117/how-to-find-the-value-closest-to-zero-using-sql-server). I changed the WHERE clause so that I could group based on other fields.

```
SELECT
Field1,
Field2,
Field3,
Value_I_Need_Closest_to_0

FROM Table

WHERE exists(select Field1
                  ,Field2
                  ,Field3
                  ,min(abs(Value_I_Need_Closest_to_0))
            from Table
            group by Field1
                  ,Field2
                  ,Field3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for:

```
select *
, min(abs(Value_I_Need_Closest_to_0)) over(partition by field1,field2, field3)
FROM tab
```